# BindView after cursor update

Tags: android

I'm trying to update a view displayed by a CursorAdapter just after its data modification.
Each row contains an image. When I touch this image, the database is update and I want to modify the image regarding this data update.

Except a requery on the cursor i didn't find a solution...My database is really big and a requery is too heavy. Do you have a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes requery is not the best solutions. What I usually do is creating helping methods in the database adapter to retrieve pieces of code. This is an excerpt of one of my adapters:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(name);

    Button btnFavorite = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.item_add_favorite);
    btnFavorite.setTag(id);
    btnFavorite.setOnClickListener(mFavoriteCliked);
}
```

What I do is basically set a click listener to the image... and make sure it takes care of change its state properly:

```
private OnClickListener mFavoriteCliked = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // change the image of the v object
    }
};
```

Comment: When database is updated, the cursor doesn't change. The image of each row will be redrawn by the old cursor in bindView(). Database changes but the view does not. How do you change the view if the cursor doesn't change? Requerying on cursor will solve the problem but it is not efficient.